# Android Studio Google-play-services library

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I need the google-play-services library and I am using Android Studio.

- I installed the google-play-service library with the SDK manager
- Added the dependencies to my build.gradle

But when I sync my project it says:

> could not found com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36

I thinks the 3.1.36 version is an old one and I dunno the right version.

What should I do ?

Comment: check `YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services` and you will see which versions you can use ...

Comment: If you're developing with Android Studio, make sure you have downloaded the "Google Repository" item using the SDK Manager.

Comment: Oh I forgot to install google-play repository. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to use that artifact, you need to install the "Google Repository" in the extras of the SDK manager, *not* "Google Play Services" as it sounds like you've done.

Comment: You can see the available versions of Play Services here:
 C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services

Comment: Had been banging my head before finding this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

is this how you are adding the dependency???

```
            buildscript {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
            }
        }


        dependencies {
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
        }


        android {
            compileSdkVersion 18
            buildToolsVersion '18.0.0'

            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res']
                }
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Select Project Settings -> Select 'Dependencies' Tab Click '+' -> 1.Library Dependencies -> Select com.google.android.gms:play-services:+

This will add the latest version of Google Play Services