# How to know the version of referenced dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Using `Android Studio` 0.3.1. In `build.gradle` I add the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
}
```

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services) it seems that you need to specify a version number after the package name. **But how do I know the version number?**

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382166/android-studio-google-play-services-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your version in this file

```
sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values/version.xml
```

Also you can check the current version here:
http://gradleplease.appspot.com/