# Correct way to import a Google sample Android project to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to play with the sample project at http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html, LocationUpdates.zip, in Android Studio.

I have tried to use File > Import Project but end up with a load of errors:
[image]

There are many questions about importing an Eclipse project to Android Studio but following those didn't help me.

Comment: Indeed, it's a reasonable request, and as the answer below admits, one *not yet covered in the documentation*.

Comment: if the pedants who roam this website down voting and close voting for no obvious reason were to put the same effort into answering questions then we'd all be much happier

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Android Studio v1.0+ now offers easy importing of the sample projects via File->Import Sample.

Update: Since v1.3 (roughly), the option can now be found at `File->New->Import sample`. (Thanks to @johanvs)

Comment: What if sample is not find in in-build list of samples? E.g.: PlacePicker developer page recommends this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlacePicker sample. But it is not include in AndroidStudio ?!?

Comment: Here's two possible options: 1) Update the samples from the SDK Manager. 2) Use the Android Studio option for 'Check out project from version control'.

Comment: File -> Import Sample is gone

Comment: File -> New -> Import Sample

Comment: Android Studio 1.5. Import Sample, and then `build xxoo Gradle project info ` forever

Comment: File -> New -> Import Sample is now also gone (2.3.3)

Comment: AS File/New/Import Sample fails and tells me to check my connection, as if it were 1975. GARBAGE..

Answer (score 3):

None of the samples have instructions for working in Android Studio yet because it's still in early-access preview, and we're waiting until it's more stable before we start reworking a lot of the documentation. You can use the project in Eclipse if you'd like to follow the directions closely.

If you want to use Android Studio, your best bet might be to create a new empty project from scratch in Android Studio and then move the code in by hand; there isn't an import function that works well yet with the Gradle-based projects that Android Studio creates by default. If you do that, make sure you have **Google Play Services** and **Goole Repository** and **Android Support Repository** installed via your SDK manager, and include a dependency to Google Play Services not by adding it via a jar library in your libs folder, but by adding a Maven-style dependency to `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'`. There are plenty of other questions on Stack Overflow that will get you going in the right direction; [Gradle build fails looking for Google Play Services in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198502/gradle-build-fails-looking-for-google-play-services-in-android-studio/20206574#20206574) is a place to start.

Comment: I'm guessing that "adding a Maven-style dependency to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'" means adding line classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36' to dependencies section of buildscript section of build.gradle?

Comment: No, thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18382420/127434 I found that it means adding compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36' to dependencies section of build.gradle.

Comment: Scott - is this possible in Android Studio yet?

Comment: Is what possible? I don't understand your question.

Comment: "there isn't an import function that works well yet with the Gradle-based projects that Android Studio creates by default"

Comment: That's still true. I'm working on that functionality right now; you can track its progress in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62122 . It's not going to land in Android Studio 0.4.3, but probably the release after that. As with many things it will be crude to start with but we'll iterate on it and make it better over time.

Comment: If you look at that bug report, it's marked as released.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 1.5 now has it under:

> `File` > `New` > `Import Sample`

Credit: @johanvs

Comment: Android Studio 1.5  Can not be trusted.

Comment: Thanks mate, helped me to figure it out