# How to import Sample Apps into Android Studio

Tags: android, import, source-code-protection

I am trying to import existing apps, such as a tuner and a metronome, into one project. Is there a way to find the source code and convert it into an android file, or would I have to recreate them? Do certain apps have certain copyright policies that prohibit users from using their codes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to import a Google sample Android project to Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422860/correct-way-to-import-a-google-sample-android-project-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **File** Menu
2. Click On **New**
3. Select **Import Sample**
4. Enter The Source Path
5. Click **Finish**